# How can i disable a class in Tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to disable a class like `list-item`.
I can disable `corePlugins.display` in configuration file, but how can i disable the `list-item` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class to the blocklist in your tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  blocklist: [
    'list-item',
  ],
  // ...
}
```

See [discarding classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#discarding-classes) in the Tailwind docs